# How to hide yellow lines in nodejs when using Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I use `visual studio code` to write `Nodejs`. But when I open the source with `VsCode`, it appears yellow lines, very annoying. How can those yellow lines not appear? Thank you

Comment: it has extra indentation so remove it

Comment: hover the mouse over the squiggle and see what the warning is